# Function of command vmware-vim-cmd vimsvc/connect?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-esx

Does anyone know the function of the command "vmware-vim-cmd vimsvc/connect (vimid)".
I thought that after executing this command with correct virtual machine id, I will be connected to the shell of this virtual machine. But it only shows "already connected" and exits.
                 Am I making some mistake in the syntax of command? Or the function of this command is completely different from what I have thought of?

Answer (score 0):

First what are you trying to do?
What is the Guest VM OS that you are trying to connect to?
What VMware products are you dealing with and what versions?

From what I gather from above you are more looking get to the command shell of a VM?  If its linux vm would just using ssh be better for what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am using ESX 3.5. Guest Os is Linux and you are right I want to access the shell of of guest os. And I can't do it through ssh because guest OS is still not on network. So brief idea here is to bring ESX on network and configure IPs of all VMs through script if above command works as per my perception.